# Hidden rows breaking report into 1 row per page in SSRS VS 2010 Shell

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to create a report that hides rows that have a particular column1 value of 0 while still using the value in column2 in the sum total.  This behavior is working by going to advanced mode and setting the Hidden property of the row I want to hide to `=iif(Fields!Column1.Value=0,TRUE,FALSE)`.

The correct rows are hidden, the total on the group is correct, however, the report displays the first page as blank and then 1 row per subsequent page both in preview and after deployment in IE. I also discovered that if the report is exported to excel it puts each row into its own sheet.  I cannot find the cause of this as the report was displaying and exporting normally before I hid the rows.

How do I fix the page break issue so that the report has a default number of rows per page and exports onto 1 sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the add page break between each instance of the group got checked off, I am not sure how but unchecking it solved the problem. It was under Parent Group>Group Properties>Page Breaks.